# How to create data frame using data table in spotfire using R script directly?

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

I have a table named 'sample' in spotfire with columns like col1,col2,col3,col4,.....,colm. I need to save as data frame using R script for that I am using the below statement:

```
tbdf <- data.frame(tbinput)
```

where 'tbinput' is my input parameter of type table and attached with table 'sample'. Is there anything I need to include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input parameter data tables get read into TERR as data frames.

You can verify this behavior by setting a document property outparam as:

```
outparam <- class(tbinput)
```

Displaying the property in a text area as 'label' shows that 'data.frame' is the class of tbinput